# R how to remove "__" when convert tbl_summary to latex

Tags: r, latex, kable, gtsummary

```
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_kable()
#> 
#> 
#> |**Characteristic**         |**Drug A**, N = 98 |**Drug B**, N = 102 |
#> |:--------------------------|:------------------|:-------------------|
#> |__Age__                    |46 (37, 59)        |48 (39, 56)         |
#> |Unknown                    |7                  |4                   |
#> |__Marker Level (ng/mL)__   |0.84 (0.24, 1.57)  |0.52 (0.19, 1.20)   |
#> |Unknown                    |6                  |4                   |
#> |__T Stage__                |                   |                    |
#> |T1                         |28 (29%)           |25 (25%)            |
#> |T2                         |25 (26%)           |29 (28%)            |
#> |T3                         |22 (22%)           |21 (21%)            |
#> |T4                         |23 (23%)           |27 (26%)            |
#> |__Grade__                  |                   |                    |
#> |I                          |35 (36%)           |33 (32%)            |
#> |II                         |32 (33%)           |36 (35%)            |
#> |III                        |31 (32%)           |33 (32%)            |
#> |__Tumor Response__         |28 (29%)           |33 (34%)            |
#> |Unknown                    |3                  |4                   |
#> |__Patient Died__           |52 (53%)           |60 (59%)            |
#> |__Months to Death/Censor__ |23.5 (17.4, 24.0)  |21.2 (14.6, 24.0)   |
```

I would like to delete "__" that surrounding variable names without manual editing in Latex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `bold_labels` step will remove the `__`

```
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
   tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
   as_kable()
```

-output

```
|**Characteristic**     |**Drug A**, N = 98 |**Drug B**, N = 102 |
|:----------------------|:------------------|:-------------------|
|Age                    |46 (37, 59)        |48 (39, 56)         |
|Unknown                |7                  |4                   |
|Marker Level (ng/mL)   |0.84 (0.24, 1.57)  |0.52 (0.19, 1.20)   |
|Unknown                |6                  |4                   |
|T Stage                |                   |                    |
|T1                     |28 (29%)           |25 (25%)            |
|T2                     |25 (26%)           |29 (28%)            |
|T3                     |22 (22%)           |21 (21%)            |
|T4                     |23 (23%)           |27 (26%)            |
|Grade                  |                   |                    |
|I                      |35 (36%)           |33 (32%)            |
|II                     |32 (33%)           |36 (35%)            |
|III                    |31 (32%)           |33 (32%)            |
|Tumor Response         |28 (29%)           |33 (34%)            |
|Unknown                |3                  |4                   |
|Patient Died           |52 (53%)           |60 (59%)            |
|Months to Death/Censor |23.5 (17.4, 24.0)  |21.2 (14.6, 24.0)   |
```

Comment: How would you bold the labels?